# C++ regex replace whole word

Tags: c++, regex, replace, cpu-word

I have a small game to do in which I need to sometimes replace some group of characters with the name of the player in the sentences.

For example, I could have a sentence like :

> "[Player]! Are you okay? A plane crash happened, it's on fire!"

And I need to replace the "[Player]" with some name contained in a std::string.

I have been looking for about 20 minutes in other SO questions and in the CPP reference and I really can't understand how to use the regex.

I would like to know how I can replace all instances of the "[Player]" string in a std::string.

Comment: Personally I would not use regex for that, a simple find and replace would likely be faster.

Comment: There are relatively small sentences, and I thought about using find and replace but if I have something like "[Player]!" I thought that it wouldn't exactly match and replace it with the actual name string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I would not use regex for this. A simple search and replace should be enough.

These are (roughly) the functions I use:

```
// change the string in-place
std::string& replace_all_mute(std::string& s,
    const std::string& from, const std::string& to)
{
    if(!from.empty())
        for(std::size_t pos = 0; (pos = s.find(from, pos) + 1); pos += to.size())
            s.replace(--pos, from.size(), to);
    return s;
}

// return a copy of the string
std::string replace_all_copy(std::string s,
    const std::string& from, const std::string& to)
{
    return replace_all_mute(s, from, to);
}

int main()
{
    std::string s = "[Player]! Are you okay? A plane crash happened, it's on fire!";

    replace_all_mute(s, "[Player]", "Uncle Bob");

    std::cout << s << '\n';
}
```

**Output:**

```
Uncle Bob! Are you okay? A plane crash happened, it's on fire!
```

Comment: Thank you! I probably could've been thoughtful about it and discover this myself, but.. really, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Regex is meant for more complex patterns. Consider, for example, that instead of simply matching `[Player]`, you wanted to match anything between brackets. That would be a good use for regex.

Following is an example that does just that. Unfortunately, the interface of `<regex>` is not flexible enough to enable dynamic replacements, so we have to implement the actual replacing ourselves.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>

int main() {
    // Anything stored here can be replaced in the string.
    std::map<std::string, std::string> vars {
        {"Player1", "Bill"},
        {"Player2", "Ted"}
    };

    // Matches anything between brackets.
    std::regex r(R"(\[([^\]]+?)\])");

    std::string str = "[Player1], [Player1]! Are you okay? [Player2] said that a plane crash happened!";

    // We need to keep track of where we are, or else we would need to search from the start of
    // the string everytime, which is very wasteful.
    // std::regex_iterator won't help, because the replacement may be smaller
    // than the match, and it would cause strings like "[Player1][Player1]" to not match properly.
    auto pos=str.cbegin();
    do {
        // First, we try to get a match. If there's no more matches, exit.
        std::smatch m;
        regex_search(pos, str.cend(), m, r);
        if (m.empty()) break;

        // The interface of std::match_results is terrible. Let's get what we need and
        // place it in apropriately named variables.
        auto var_name = m[1].str();
        auto start = m[0].first;
        auto end = m[0].second;

        auto value = vars[var_name];

        // This does the actual replacement
        str.replace(start, end, value);

        // We update our position. The new search will start right at the end of the replacement.
        pos = m[0].first + value.size();
    } while(true);

    std::cout << str;
}
```

Output:

```
Bill, Bill! Are you okay? Ted said that a plane crash happened!
```

### [See it live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a8c9823fc08fd1f2)

Answer (score 0):

Simply find and replace, e.g. `boost::replace_all()`

```
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>

std::string target(""[Player]! Are you okay? A plane crash happened, it's on fire!"");
boost::replace_all(target, "[Player]", "NiNite");
```

Answer (score 0):

As some people have mentioned, find and replace might be more useful for this scenario, you could do something like this.

```
std::string name = "Bill";
std::string strToFind = "[Player]";
std::string str = "[Player]! Are you okay? A plane crash happened, it's on fire!";
str.replace(str.find(strToFind), strToFind.length(), name);
```